# Bring chrome to the foreground when moving a chrome tab to a different window

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I tend to move my tabs around all my monitors frequently. But I also have other applications like Slack or my IDE open covering the whole window. Over a workday, I tend to end up with more than 7-8 open chrome instances simply because it creates a new window when a tab is dropped onto a non-chrome window.

When I drag out a Tab from Chrome and move to a different monitor, I'd like an existing Chrome instance (on that screen) to pop to the foreground and accept the tab, as opposed to creating a new window. Is there an existing feature/plugin for that?

Answer (score 1):

##### Chrome Tab Manager

---

Instead of dragging the tab to your other display, use a tab manager to drag the tab between Chrome Windows.

I quickly installed and tested a number of tab managers on your behalf.  Of the half dozen I tested, I reccomend **Tabli** a minimalist and open source product ([MIT License](https://github.com/antonycourtney/tabli/blob/master/LICENSE)) that appears well targeted at your needs.

| Tabli Tab Manager |  |
| --- | --- |
| Google: | [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabli/igeehkedfibbnhbfponhjjplpkeomghi) |
| Github Project: | [github.com/antonycourtney/tabli](https://github.com/antonycourtney/tabli) |
| Website: | [GetTabli.com](https://www.gettabli.com/) |
| User Guide: | [gettabli.com/tabli-usage.html](https://www.gettabli.com/tabli-usage.html) |
| Video Tour: | [youtube.com/watch?v=vD6YOvSa7M0v](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vD6YOvSa7M0) |

##### Example Usage

---

1. Click the tabli extension icon
   [image]
2. Select the tab to be moved with your mouse
   [image]
3. Drag tab to other window
   [image]